# Перебор букв/цифр в цикле в обратном порядке Python 3

Tags: python

Как имея строку с цифрами и буквами создать цикл который будет перебирать его в обратном порядке?

Задаем строку: avc3d

Цикл выдает: avc3с, avc3b, avc3a, avc2z, avc2y, avc2x....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```
from numpy import base_repr
s = 'avc3d'
for i in range(int(s, 36), 0, -1):
    print(base_repr(i, 36).lower())
```

Представляем строку как число в 36сс и проходим в обратном порядке уже по числам.

Если не хотите использовать модуль numpy, можно воспользоваться функцией [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1181922/7485582).

```
def base36encode(number, alphabet='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'):
    """Converts an integer to a base36 string."""
    if not isinstance(number, (int, long)):
        raise TypeError('number must be an integer')

    base36 = ''
    sign = ''

    if number < 0:
        sign = '-'
        number = -number

    if 0 <= number < len(alphabet):
        return sign + alphabet[number]

    while number != 0:
        number, i = divmod(number, len(alphabet))
        base36 = alphabet[i] + base36

    return sign + base36
```